# Python 2's .decode("hex")

Tags: python

I'm having some trouble understanding Python 2's `foo.decode("hex")` command . Solving [this problem](https://cryptopals.com/sets/1/challenges/4) I obtained the following in Python 2.7.12 (where words_alpha.txt is a 4 MB dictionary).

```
words = open("words_alpha.txt").read().split('\n')
def xor(x, y):
    if len(x) == len(y):
        return "".join([chr(ord(x[i]) ^ ord(y[i])) for i in range(len(x))])

def single_char_xors(msg):
    for i in range(128):
        yield [chr(i), xor(msg, chr(i)*len(msg))]


def real_word_count(S): # Assumes there is at least one three-letter word in the string S.
    count = 0
        for word in filter(lambda s: s.isalpha() and len(s) >= 3, S.split(' ')):
            if word.lower() in words:
                count += 1
        return count

hexes = open("4.txt").read().split('\n')
hexes = [x.decode("hex") for x in hexes]
answer = []
maxwc = 0
for x in hexes:
    for y in single_char_xors(x):
        if real_word_count(y[1]) > maxwc:
            answer = [x] + y
            maxwc = real_word_count(y[1])

print answer[0] + " xor " + answer[1] + " is " + answer[2]
```

In Python 3, `foo.decode("hex")` is deprecated. but replacing `hexes = [x.decode("hex") for x in hexes]` with `hexes = [binascii.unhexlify(x).decode() for x in hexes]` gives

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe8 in position 3: invalid continuation byte

whereas `hexes = [binascii.unhexlify(x).decode("utf-8", "ignore") for x in hexes]` (or `"replace"`, `"backslashreplace"`, etc.) works fine. So what is `foo.decode("hex")` doing that `binascii.unhexlify(foo).decode()` does not do by default?

Comment: `[binascii.unhexlify(x).decode() for x in hexes]` decodes one byte at a time. UTF8 is a multi-byte encoding; that's why it gives the error.

Comment: Well, <code>[binascii.unhexlify(x).decode("utf-8")</code> gives the same error...

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is with `.decode("utf-8", "ignore")` - with the `"ignore"` parameter you effectively ignore the issue that raises the `UnicodeDecodeError` exception in the first case.

Comment: How is that the problem?

Comment: It is not the problem but the basis for the difference. By default any conversion to Unicode is strict.

Answer (score 0):

Differences between `binascii.hexlify` and `codecs.decode`:

- **binascii.hexlify**

  Hexadecimal representation of binary data.

  The return value is a bytes object.

  Type:      builtin_function_or_method
- **codecs.decode**

  .decode(obj, encoding='utf-8', errors='strict')

  Decodes obj using the codec registered for encoding.Errors may be given to set the desired error handling scheme. The default error handler is 'strict' meaning that decoding errors raise ValueError (or a more codec specific subclass, such as UnicodeDecodeError). Refer to Codec Base Classes for more information on codec error handling.

  Type:      builtin_function_or_method